# Verify breadcrumbs path

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm attempting to verify that a breadcrumb path is present on a page. I'm able to verify the first to pieces as they are links and can easily be found  using the following xpath:

```
.//div[@id = 'nav']/a[text() = 'Home']/following-sibling::a[text() = 'Acme Automation']
```

I'd like to include the Group List part of the path but since the text belongs to the previous div, I can't seem to include it in the xpath I have above so that it can clearly show the path is Home ¬ Acme Automation ¬ Group List. I am able to find the Group list text using:

```
.//div[@id = 'nav' and contains(normalize-space(), 'Group List')]
```

So overall i just want to verify the breadcrumb path and not just the fact that the elements are on the page... Any pointers?

```
<div id="nav">
  Nav:
<a href="https://google.com">Home</a>
 ¬ 
<a href="https://google.com">Acme Automation</a>
 ¬ Group List
</div>
```